# docker, invalid reference format

Tags: image, ubuntu, docker, push

I'm new to docker and trying to learn how to push and pull. I've been stuck with this problem for a while. I'm trying to push and image to my docker, but keep getting the same error "Invalid reference format" see picture for details.

[image: trying to push to my docker]

Answer (score 3):

Before pushing the local image to the repository, you should tag the image with the repository url:

```
docker tag staticwebserver:v1 <registry-url/repository>staticwebserver:v1
```

Then you push the tagged image:

```
docker push <registry-url/repository>staticwebserver:v1
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `[]`, it should be `staticwebserver:v1`. Docker doesn't understand the format which you are trying to use/post with the registry.

Comment: Doing what you suggested gave me a new error: "The push refers to repository [docker.cs.hioa/sxx/staticwebserver]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: docker.cs.hioa/sxxx/staticwebserver

Comment: That's expected, you need to tag your local image & push it to the registry.